# Getting an index to run one at a time in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a quick question here. Is there a way to stop a for loop and wait for one index to be done before the next one can execute? I'll try to be clear as much as possible so apologize if my question and my code aren't clear enough. Plus, I will give more explanation for whatever clues that you can give me. Much appreciate

- So I try to get each id to put on my API, in order to trigger the script to be run. However, the requirement is 1 script has to be done first before the next one can be trigger.

I was messing around with setTimeOut() but looks like it doesn't give me what I need. And sorry guys, my project isn't allowed me to work with any external libraries and either async await

```
 function sampleScriptRunning(activity){
    var ID = activity.map(function(activity){return activity.ID})
             for(var i = 0; i < ID.length; i++){
                      if(ID[i] === 'undefined'){
                        console.log('No more scripts to run')
                        return;
                            }
       Api.getActivityStatus(ID[i]).then(function(response){
   return $http.post('/proxy/api/nodejsjob/' + response.sample.sample[0].ScriptId + '/run')
       })
```

Comment: Take a look below, this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to manage asynchronous calls in series, you have two options - `Promise` objects, or managing callbacks yourself.

One powerful tool you can use is the [`mapSeries`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) functionality of `bluebird`, a npm module for promise management. That way, you can execute the commands only one at a time without any other management:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const ids = activities.map((activity) => activity.id);
return Promise.mapSeries(ids, (id) => {
  return Api.getActivityStatus(ID[i])
    .then(() => $http.post('/proxy/api/nodejsjob/' + response.sample.sample[0].ScriptId + '/run'))
});
```

Comment: could he not execute in an `async IIFE` and use `await` ?

Comment: I appreciate your help Bibberty, but sorry, unfortunately my project isn't allowed me to work with any external libraries and either async await

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can wrap you work in an `async IIFE` and then use the `await` statement to `sync` your `async`.

```js
// This is just a dummy Async function, it will randomly return (to simulate true async issues)
function doAsync(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(`here is - ${i}`) }, Math.random()*1000);
  });
}

// This function when called will execute an IIFE to allow us to use await.
function workSyncronously() {
  (async () => {
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      let message = await doAsync(i);
      console.log(message);
    }
  })();
}

workSyncronously();
```

So lets look at something where we need the results of **two functions** before continuing:

Slight tweak to the code, now we are using the result of our first call to drive the second call.

```js
// This is just a dummy Async function, it will randomly return (to simulate true async issues)
function doAsync(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(i*2) }, Math.random()*1000);
  });
}

// This function when called will execute an IIFE to allow us to use await.
function workSyncronously() {
  (async () => {
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      let timeTwo = await doAsync(i);
      let timeFour = await doAsync(timeTwo);
      console.log(`${i} *2=${timeTwo} *4=${timeFour}`);
    }
  })();
}

workSyncronously();
```

So you code might look something like this:

```
function sampleScriptRunning(activity) {
  const IDArray = activity.map({
    ID
  } => ID);
  const postResponses = [];

  (asnyc() => {
    for (let id of IDArray) {
      let response = await Api.getActivityStatus(id);
      let postResponse = await $http.post('/proxy/api/nodejsjob/' + response.sample.sample[0].ScriptId + '/run');
      postResponses.push(postResponse);
    }
    return postResponses;
  })();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Bibberty, but sorry, unfortunately my project isn't allowed me to work with any external libraries and either async await

Comment: No external libraries required there. But you cannot use `async` / `await` ?

Comment: yup, I'm not trying to be an a** hole or anything, but yeah, it's not allowed me to use async/await in my app

Comment: Nope, thats fair. Ok. You may need a state engine. Run script on a `Promise` and in the `then` set a new `nextID`. Then you need a while loop and just execute a new script each time the `nextID` changes.